# Quartz composer alternative for iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, quartz-graphics

I´m working on a project where I found that quartz composer was perfect for my needs could it only be used with iOS. I've been looking at [Opacity](http://likethought.com/opacity/) but it's no good for animations. I would like to be able to work with animations as in QC and be able to give give input from code.

What good alternatives (if such exists) would you recommend? And if not an editor like QC, how would you recommend approaching programming interactive animations from scratch in iOS? Cocos2d?

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not clear. What exactly do you mean by "was perfect for my needs". What do you want to do / achieve ? "programming interactive animations from scratch" is very broad.

Comment: I'll give an example. I'd like to be able to create an animation, say a rotating 3d cube. I would then like to be able to change things like the cube's rotating speed or size with values send from code, i.e. an iOS app. Imagine a swipe on the screen that would make the cube rotate faster.

Comment: For 3D you should use OpenGL ES.

Comment: Thank your for answering. Yes I'm aware that OpenGl ES would be the language for that, but I'm looking for an editor like Quartz Composer that would work for iOS.

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question. The only alternative I've found that is [opengl shader builder](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGLShaderBuilderUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html) by Apple which is not like quartz composer, but allows you to program and change running annimations or graphics - which will run on the iOS. The program, however, is not so easy to use compared to Apple standards.

Answer (score 1):

I recently found out that someone has been working on a Quartz Composer port for iOS:
http://joris.kluivers.nl/blog/2013/06/04/quartz-composer-for-ios/

Didn't test it though, and he says it's not close to being complete, but anyway looks promising.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [Core Animation API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for iOS?  I'm not sure what kind of animations you would like to perform, but Core Animation seems to be a full featured API and I think it's a "friendlier" interface according to Apple's standards.

Comment: Yes I do know Core Animation, but what I was looking for was some sort of visual editor like quartz composer, which does not work for iOS. I apologize for my question not not being completely clear.

Comment: I see, you were looking for a composition tool, not the ability to compose in the code.